# Ubuntu 12.04 using wubi won't load up

Tags: 12.04, wubi

So I'm trying to install Ubuntu using the wubi client. Everything goes fine, but when it restarts and tries to load up ubuntu, I get to the purple screen and it says "Preparing to start up for the first time" or something like that. I can't get passed this screen, it just stays there until I restart the computer. Can anyone help me out with this? Would really appreciate it.

Graphics card currently in use is a GeForce 9200 if that helps any.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: The duplicate post refers to a black screen, but in fact the symptoms can also be a frozen screen showing purple, mosaic patterns, graphics corruption. Also, in general, Wubi installs (which are unattended) only hang up due to graphics drivers (nvidia/radeon) because Wubi checks the `md5sum` of the ISO prior to installing. Please refer to this discussion for more info: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7564/discussion-between-eliah-kagan-and-bcbc

Comment: @user133118 Refer to this answer in the duplicate thread: http://askubuntu.com/a/257917/14916